# Can I pass ref of React <div /> to third-party DOM-based library right in the JSX in render() method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, ref

I'm using React and trying to integrate it with some third-party DOM-based library.
Can i pass the DOM node of `<div />` to render library data (i.e. plotly.js or Google Maps) right in the `ref` lambda function (from JSX in `render()` method)?

**Example**:
I have a component like this:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return <div ref={e => { this.element = e }} />
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.renderChart(this.element)
  }

  renderChart(e) {
    // skipping for the sake of brevity
  }
}
```

My question is if I can refactor it to:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return <div ref={this.renderChart} />
  }

  renderChart(e) {
    // skipping for the sake of brevity
  }
}
```

Comment: yup, even `ref={this.renderChart}` should work

Comment: Refactoring as you suggest will reassign that reference every time the render function is called. The question is do you need `this.element` to be available as a reference outside of the `renderChart()` method? If that plugin has a destructor, you'll want to call it in `componentWillUnmount()` as well.

Comment: Any other drawbacks except inability to use a destruction lifecycle hook?

Comment: @azium thanks. Applied your shorthand.